# Incremental Addition in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to perform Incremental Addition in excel as below

Initial A1
Next-Day will be A1+A2
After That A1+A2+A3 so on ...

Can anyone please help me getting formula for the same. How I can do in excel

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a mix of relative and fixed cell references in Excel.

Put this SUM formula in B1 cell and drag it down till your entries in column A

```
=SUM($A$1:A1)
```